# Angular + Django Rest Framework rearranging array on SPA, separate severs works okay

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I have a random issue happening.

When I run Angular and Django one separate instances (`ng serve --poll 2000` & `python manage.py runserver`) my data is transferred as expected and works okay.

When I build my angular project and run via apache2 using django as the entry point for the application I have an array which becomes reordered every time.
`node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --output-path ../backend/static/ang --output-hashing none`

The array is loaded with the same contents on different pages and can be in any order. There are 4 primary categories and its these which are reordered. The ITEM1, ITEM2, ITEM3 and ITEM4 below.

I have no idea why.

The code which makes the nodes is below:

```
    def get(self, request):
        response = {}

        subjects = ['ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3', 'ITEM4']
        for subject in subjects:
            try:
                alltitles = TitlePageTitles.objects.filter(title__contains=str(subject))
                response.update({subject : []})
                
                titleslist = []
                returnedJson = {}
                returnedList = []
                returnedJsonString = ""
                for title in alltitles:
                    titleslist = list(TitlePageItems.objects.filter(ks_key=title.title).order_by('id').values())
                    newJsonItem = {
                        "id": 0, 
                        "ks_key": title.title,
                        "item_text_display": title.title.replace("_"," "), 
                        "item_text_link": title.title.replace("_"," "), 
                        "order": -1, 
                        "page_id": 0, 
                        "children": ArrayToNested(titleslist)
                    }
                    returnedList.append(newJsonItem)
                response.update({subject : returnedList})
                    
            except Exception as inst:
                print(inst)

        returnedList2 = []
        for key, value in response.items():
            #logger.error(key)
            newJsonItem = {
                        "id": 0, 
                        "ks_key": key,
                        "item_text_display": key.replace("_"," "), 
                        "item_text_link": key.replace("_"," "), 
                        "order": -2, 
                        "page_id": 0, 
                        "children": value
                    }
            returnedList2.append(newJsonItem)
        response2 = {}
        response2['Menu'] = returnedList2
        return JsonResponse(response2, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem's I'm not able to sort this so I've added a sort method which is run in angular after the response is received which sorts the first tier of items in the json array.

```
sortNodes(nodes)
  {
    var processing = true;
    var foundSwitch = false;
    while(processing)
    {
      nodes.forEach(function(i, idx, array){
        foundSwitch = false;
        if (idx != array.length - 1)
        {
          console.log(array[idx]['item_text_display'])
          console.log(array[idx + 1]['item_text_display'])
           if (array[idx]['item_text_display'].localeCompare(array[idx + 1]['item_text_display']) > 0 )
           {
             console.log("switch")
             const tempitem = array[idx + 1];
             array[idx + 1] = array[idx];
             array[idx] = tempitem;
             console.log(array)
             foundSwitch = true;
           }
        }

      });
      if (!foundSwitch)
      {
        break;
      }
      
    }
    return nodes;
  }
```